# Python - programming a multiple-choice quiz program (i.e. Driver's License exam)

Tags: python

I'm working on a project; to program a Driver's License Exam that has 20 multiple-choice questions.And I have a list of 20 correct answers. 
1.A
2.C 
3..
4... so on.

-program must store the correct answers in a list.

-The program should get the student’s answers for each of the 20 questions and store the answers in another list.

-After the student’s answers have been entered, the program should display a message indicating whether the student passed or failed the exam. (A student must correctly answer 15 of the 20 questions to pass the exam.)

The program should then display:
17. B 18. B 19. D 20. A

￼-the total number of correctly answered questions

-the total number of incorrectly answered questions

-a list showing the question numbers of the incorrectly answered questions.

.
.
.

**just wanted to get some ideas from others, if you were to write this program how would you approach ? need some advise :) and I'm not asking for any CODE , I want to solve this program but don't know where to begin..any inputs? I'm new to python and I took a beginner level Java course**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How would you have approached this problem in your Java class?

Comment: This isn't an advice forum. If you have a specific question about how you implemented it, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach I would take (no code) is the following:
A. Put the correct answers in a list in the proper order.
B. Ask for user input (with the input function)
C. Append their answer to a different list.
D. Inside of a loop check if the user answer is correct, if not append the correct answer to a new list along with the loop variable for the number. Also update a counting variable if the answer is incorrect.
E. Display using a print statement.

Comment: Very Clear Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of lists, use dictionaries so that {Q1 : answer} is the format, then you can loop over the answers and count the correct/incorrect answers.